# Azure AD Application - how to set some parameters from C# or Powershell?

Tags: c#, powershell, azure, automation, azure-active-directory

i am trying to register application in Azure this way (i run this script from C# app, some variables are generated with Runtime Text Template, <#= #> are constants then):

```
Import-Module AzureRM.Resources
Login-AzureRmAccount 
$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation "cert:\CurrentUser\My" -Subject "CN=Test" -KeySpec KeyExchange
$keyValue = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($cert.GetRawCertData())
$app = New-AzureRmADApplication -DisplayName "<#= Model.ManageApplicationName #>" -HomePage "https://<#= Model.Domain #>/<#= Model.ManageApplicationName #>" -IdentifierUris "https://<#= Model.Domain #>/<#= Model.ManageApplicationName #>"  -AvailableToOtherTenants $true -CertValue $keyValue -EndDate $cert.NotAfter -StartDate $cert.NotBefore
$app.ApplicationId
New-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId $app.ApplicationId
Start-Sleep -s 30
New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -RoleDefinitionName Contributor -ServicePrincipalName $app.ApplicationId.Guid
```

This works nice, i can see app in portal...

Then i need to obtain access token to use it in Microsoft.Azure.Management.Resources library to manage some resources.

So i need to get application key/client secret, to obtain token via ClientCredentials, is it possible to do it in Powershell or via API?

Then i tried to do it another way. I followed this tutorial from documentation: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-manager-api-authentication/

I found this issue calling https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/OAuth2/Authorize from tutorial, of course with my own values:

AADSTS65005: The client application has requested access to resource .... This request has failed because the client has not specified this resource in its requiredResourceAccess list.

- This was fixed when i set Windows Azure Service Management API permission in portal - Can this be done from C# or Powershell?

AADSTS50011: No reply address is registered for the application.

- This was fixed when i set Reply URL - Can this be done from C# or Powershell?

I am confused, because in documentation there is nothing about this additional manual settings. Problem is a need to automate whole process. So i need to create app in AD and get access token without any clicks in Portal. Hope it is possible.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This was fixed when i set Windows Azure Service Management API permission in portal - Can this be done from C# or Powershell?

Yes, we are able to grant the OAuth 2.0 permission to the app using the Azure AD Graph REST. To make this rest, we require the administrator of the tenant. And we still need an application which already grant the permission to **Access the directory as the signed-in user**. Then we can acquire the token with the administrator based on the **OAuth2.0 code grant flow**. At last we can update the application with REST request below to assign the **Windows Azure Service Management API** to apps:

```
Patch: graph.windows.net/adfei.onmicrosoft.com/applications/{objectIdOfApplication}?api-version=1.6
authorization: bearer {token}
{
            "requiredResourceAccess": [
            {
                "resourceAppId": "797f4846-ba00-4fd7-ba43-dac1f8f63013",
                "resourceAccess": [
                    {
                        "id": "41094075-9dad-400e-a0bd-54e686782033",
                        "type": "Scope"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "resourceAppId": "00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
                "resourceAccess": [
                    {
                        "id": "311a71cc-e848-46a1-bdf8-97ff7156d8e6",
                        "type": "Scope"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "cba73afc-7f69-4d86-8450-4978e04ecd1a",
                        "type": "Scope"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "a42657d6-7f20-40e3-b6f0-cee03008a62a",
                        "type": "Scope"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
 }
```

The `resourceAppId` 797f4846-ba00-4fd7-ba43-dac1f8f63013 is for **Windows Azure Service Management API**, and **00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000** is for the **Windows Azure Active Directory** which the app I config before. You can get the application for the exits requiredResourceAccess and append the `resourceAppId` **797f4846-ba00-4fd7-ba43-dac1f8f63013**.

> This was fixed when i set Reply URL - Can this be done from C# or Powershell?

Yes. We can use [`Set-AzureRmADApplication`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt490393(v=azure.300).aspx) which in Azure Power Shell 3.0 to set the `ReplyUrls`. And you can also specify it when you create the application( refer [New-AzureRmADApplication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt679017%28v=azure.300%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)).

Comment: Well, i can make user type or, in the worst case, give me his login and password. Still i need to have some alredy registered app? I really need to do it in a way, that user just give me his creds and everything else is done for him...

Comment: Yes, you are correct. To use the Azure AD Graph grant the permission, we still need a app which has been register and have the permission to allow us to perform this action.

Comment: Ok, i understand that Graph think. Any chance to do it the other way, like some Powershell script? Or Graph is the only way how can i set that permission?

Comment: @Enemim As far as I know, there is no such PowerShell script like REST at present version of [resource manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/resourcemanager/azurerm.resources/v3.3.0/get-azurermroledefinition)